# PHP - Replacing multiple sets of placeholders while looping through arrays

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, placeholder

I am working on a piece of code to help me create an email body based on values scraped from a website.
But I am having problems replacing placeholders with values.

My "replace placeholder" code looks like this:

```
foreach ($products as $productID) 
{
    $product_array = scrape_product($scrape_url, $productID);

    foreach ($product_array as $key => $value)
    {
        $pattern = '/\#' . $key . '\#/';
        $email_body = preg_replace($pattern, $value, $email_body, $product_count);
    }
}
```

The function scrape_product($scrape_url, $productID); returns a number of arrays that looks like this:

```
$product_array = array(
    "PRODUCTID" => $ID,
    "TITLE"     => $productname,
    "ONELINER"  => $oneliner,
    "PRICE"     => $price,
    "PRICE_ORG" => $price_org,
    "DISCOUNT"  => $discount,
    "IMAGE"     => $image,
    "URL"       => $scrape_url,
);
```

The arrays consist or key value pairs and for each array I get back I loop through my email template looking for a placeholder in the format #key# -> for example #PRODUCTID#.

I then use this:

```
$pattern = '/\#' . $key . '\#/';
$email_body = preg_replace($pattern, $value, $email_body, $product_count);
```

To replace the placeholders with the corresponding placeholder.

So here is my problem:
In my email template there are are several occurrences of the same placeholder (i.e #PRODUCTID#) - to be exact there is a complete set of placeholders for each array.

But I cannot get the code to replace the placeholders correctly... like:

```
array1 -> placeholder set1
array2 -> placeholder set2
array3 -> placeholder set3
and so on...
```

My system allows up to a total of 12 products = 12 arrays with product info that needs to be put in the email template. But right now it replaces the placeholder with the values from array 1 and then finished (because there are no placeholders left after the first runthrough).

The variable $product_count holds the number of product arrays (can be anything from 1-12)

I have already tried using strtr() and str_replace() without any luck.

Help, input or hints would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE - added an example of my template**

```
<table width="285" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" style="text-align: left; margin-left: 5px; table-layout: fixed;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="284" valign="middle" colspan="2">
            <a href="#URL##PRODUCTID#/?ssel=false&utm_campaign=%%jobid%%-%%xtyear%%%%xtmonthnumeric%%%%xtday%%&utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=#PRODUCTID#" target="_blank">
                <img src="#IMAGE#" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; border: 0pt none; margin: 0px;" width="200" height="150" alt="#TITLE#"  />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" height="3" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1%;"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="font-family: arial; font-size: 15px; color: #363636; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <td width="285" valign="top" colspan="2">
            #TITLE#
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="font-family: arial; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 100; color: #363636;">
        <td height="85" align="left" valign="top" style="height: 85px; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: arial; text-align-left; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td height="3" style="height:3px; font-size:1px; line-height:1%;"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" height="54" style="height: 54px;">
                        #ONELINER#
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table width="285" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" style="text-align: left; margin-left: 5px; table-layout: fixed;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="284" valign="middle" colspan="2">
            <a href="#URL##PRODUCTID#/?ssel=false&utm_campaign=%%jobid%%-%%xtyear%%%%xtmonthnumeric%%%%xtday%%&utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=#PRODUCTID#" target="_blank">
                <img src="#IMAGE#" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; border: 0pt none; margin: 0px;" width="200" height="150" alt="#TITLE#"  />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" height="3" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1%;"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="font-family: arial; font-size: 15px; color: #363636; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <td width="285" valign="top" colspan="2">
            #TITLE#
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="font-family: arial; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 100; color: #363636;">
        <td height="85" align="left" valign="top" style="height: 85px; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" valign="top" style="font-family: arial; text-align-left; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td height="3" style="height:3px; font-size:1px; line-height:1%;"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" height="54" style="height: 54px;">
                        #ONELINER#
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

As you (hopefully) can see in the template code the placeholders appear more than once (for instance #ONELINER#).

I want to replace the #ONELINER# placeholder with the oneliner value for product 1 the first time I meet the placeholder. The second time it should be the value for product 2 and so on...

Hope this makes sense.

***UPDATE***

Here is an example of an product array that needs to be replaced into my template. As requested by dynamic.

```
PRODUCTID -> 50107639XX
TITLE -> Sony XPERIA Z1 Compact 
ONELINER -> Det bedste fra Sony i en kompakt, vandtæt smartphone
PRICE -> 2500
PRICE_ORG -> 5000
DISCOUNT -> 50% 
IMAGE -> //media.jflindt.dk/image/49377/500/400/sony-xperia-z1-compact-16gb-sort.jpg
URL -> http://www.jflindt.dk/product/
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually for such simple replacing you don't need `preg`. You can use `str_replace();`

```
$search = array(
   '#PRODUCTID#',
   '#TYPE#',
   '#CAT#'
);

$replace = array(
   'val1',
   'val2',
   'val3'
);

$text = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
```

As Amal pointed out, if you have an array of pairs:

```
$pairs = array(
    "#PRODUCTID#" => $ID,
    "#TITLE#"     => $productname,
    "#ONELINER#"  => $oneliner
);
```

You can use `strtr();`

```
$text = strtr($text, $pairs);
```

Altho I personally  prefer `str_replace` due to its name. If you need to build the `$search` and `$replace` arrays, having a single array of `$pairs`, you can do:

```
$search = array_keys($pairs);
$replace = array_values($pairs);
```

Comment: I've tried str_replace() and strtr() already and they do not not solve the problem... the closest I have gotten is with preg_replace.

Comment: then you was not clear in the question. Post a snippet of your text that need to be replaced and a print_r of your values

Comment: dynamic - I have added a sample of my template and a sample of a product array

Comment: jflindt, that is wrong by design. You should have a template of your item (I if understood correctly it is a full table). Then you should append each table with consecutive call to str_replace

Comment: dynamic - I see your point... I'll try populating the product tables **before** adding them to the email body...

Comment: Be careful with `str_replace` in general. it has two defaults: 1) it parses all the string for each replacement pairs 2) (consequence of 1)) this can results to circular replacements with something like `array('A'=>'B', 'B'=>'A')`. `strtr` haven't these two problems and is much faster.